# Display recaptcha error message on the same page

Tags: php, recaptcha

I've got 2 pages.

Page 1 has a form which posts values to page 2

Page 2 has the following:

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {

    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again. " .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");

} else {
```

Instead of display the `die` output on page 2, how do I display that value or a more appropriate value on page 1 under the recaptcha control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an on page 1 `if (isset($_POST['submit')){...}` block. In this block you check the recaptcha and `echo ""` the error message.

Comment: I have this  <form method="post" name="contactform" action= "<?php echo $action ?> " >  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){.... {.$action="contactengine.php";}.....}   I like to have my action dynamic..somehow it didn't work.  Is there such a way to write dynamic action in form?.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the request to page1 and also add the recaptcha code there. Then you can set a variable called `$error` if there was an error instead of calling `die(...);`. Then, after the recaptcha form, you can check if `$error` is set and then display an error message. This will look like the following snipet:

```
if( isset( $error ) ) {
    echo '<p class="error">' . $error . '</p>';
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your form to page 1 and check if captcha is correct there:

- If it's not correct, you can display message somewhere near the form itself,
- If it's correct, you can set cookie / set some session variable and redirect to page 2,

Other way would be, on page 2, instead of `die` redirecting back to page 1 if captcha wasn't correct (and you can set some session variable aswell to display error on page 1 after redirecting)

Answer (score 0):

Yoг get the error status in one script, but want to use the value in other. It has next resolve:
1) Use $_SESSION array to save validation status
in script 2:

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {

    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    $_SESSION['error_status'] = $resp->error;

} else {
```

in script 1:

```
if ($_SESSION['error_status']){
    echo "<p class='error'>{$_SESSION['error_status']}</p>"
}
```

2) OR you can add error_status in header('Location: http://you_site.com/?error_status='.$error_code);
in second script